# Ruby -> PostgreSQL connection with pg_hba.conf set to "ident sameuser" instead of "trust"

Tags: ruby, postgresql, database-connection, ident

I've tried every Google search term I can think of but everything I dig up keeps saying to set local connections to `trust` in `pg_hba.conf` (seems like a security hole if anyone locally can log in and access the DB as anyone they say they are).

In `pg_hba.conf` local connections are set to `ident sameuser`.  The script should be running as that user, but I get this error:

```
A database error occurred: 
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

The Ruby code is pretty generic:

```
conn_str = "DBI:pg:dbname=mydb;host=" + localhost
@connection = DBI.connect(conn_str, "myuser", '')
```

I can work around this by creating a `~/.pgpass` file [as described here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html),
but I'd prefer being able to let users log in and just access the DB server.

Anyone ever been able to get PostgreSQL's `ident sameuser` to work properly for local scripts?

Comment: The version number of your PostgreSQL would be of help. Also, I wrote a [detailed answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8915572/939860) two days ago. May be of help.

Comment: Erwin: the ident setting doesn't work for these Ruby scripts.  That's what I'm trying to get to work.  The .pgpass works.  I'm sure your environment variable method works as well, but both will leave the password in cleartext if you know where to look :-P
Postgresql Version is 8.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this:

> In pg_hba.conf **local** connections are set to ident sameuser. The script should be running as that user, but I get this error [...]

```
conn_str = "DBI:pg:dbname=mydb;host=" + localhost
@connection = DBI.connect(conn_str, "myuser", '')
```

Please note that a "local" connection is not the same as a connection to "localhost". As soon as you mention "localhost" in the connection URL a TCP/IP socket is created. These are managed by the `host` rules in `pg_hba.conf.

To use a real "local" connection Unix Domain Sockets must be used. But I don't know whether or not the Ruby DBI connector supports them.

Comment: Thanks, A.H.  That did it.  Changed the string to this:
conn_str = "DBI:pg:dbname=mydb"
and ident connections work fine now :-)  Adding the "host=" parameter in the connection string apparently converts it from using local connections via sockets to TCP/IP...this behavior isn't the same as in MSSQL which treats connections to localhost as local connections...

Answer (score 1):

The ident setting works for me for local system users and PostgreSQL 8.4. You may have to adjust your `pg_hba.conf` settings.

Check your database log files to see where the connections come from exactly and whether the system user name matches the database role name. You may have to activate [`log_connections` in your postgresql.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) for that.

The manual really does a nice job explaining [authentication methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-methods.html).

If system user name and database role name don't match, you'll have to use a .pgpass file. But your passwords should still be safe. Only the system user `postgres` gets to read it. I [quote the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html):

> On Unix systems, the permissions on .pgpass must disallow any access
>   to world or group; achieve this by the command chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass.